# Publish (FTP) fails from MSBUILD

Tags: powershell, ftp, msbuild

If I publish with my website with Visual Studio (using FileSystem) it works fine.

Now I'm attempting to do the same from Powershell.

```
.\MSBuild.exe $sln /p:PublishProfile=MyTestProfile /p:PublishProvider=FileSystem /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=False /p:DeployOnBuild=False /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0 /v:diag
```

The above is based upon the output window (of Visual Studio) when I publish (using diagnostic output). Things are copied and pasted to avoid typos.

The problem I have is it never publishes!

I am now shown the following message from Powershell:

Build FAILED.

> "C:\Users\me\source\repos\Test03\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
>     C:\Users\me\source\repos\Test03\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj(265,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

This issue appears to be well documented here on SO but, I already have VS installed, and this isn't a build server. It's all being done on my one machine... However, if I try to get to the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` it doesn't exist. I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\` but within this folder only 1 folder called FileTracker.

This now confuses me more because it works from within Visual Studio, but not within Powershell.

Comment: Double-check what's in the publish profile named "MyTestProfile". If you're really sure you feed the same file through cmd as through PowerShell, then compare using for example ProcMon what the differences are between executing exactly the same command via cmd and PowerShell.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for the comment. You were right, after comparing the output, the main issue was I was using Visual Studio Version 14 but VS was using Visual Studio Version 15. I updated my post as it's a different error (yet still preventing me from publishing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with

```
.\MSBuild.exe $sln /p:PublishProfile=MyTestProfile /p:PublishProvider=FileSystem /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=False /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:AspnetMergePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools" /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0 #/v:diag
```

You may not have the path for the correct visual studio version. Downloading .NET Core SDK should provide this https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

However, you may need to update to the correct path for the build path (where msbuild.exe exists).

I then had to add /p:AspnetMergePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools"  manually for reasons I don't understand. I understand that it coudln't find this path, but I didn't understand why it can't find the path when VS could!

Comment: In case someone else makes there way here with the same problem would be beneficial if you explain why this works